# Can we trigger function just before session expired in .net core so that we can log the user last activity?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to trigger event just before the user session has expired . Is there any function like session_end so that we can log the activity.
here, is the code is used to setup the session

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/admin/ClearSession";
            options.Cookie.Name = "SessionToken.Identity";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            options.SlidingExpiration = false;

        });
```

Comment: It's often hard to rely on a message when the session ends. Sessions can timeout without the server getting notified. What about logging all actions with overwriting the previous one. This way, only the last action remains in your log.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a specific way to know the cookie expired.
You can make use of `OnRedirectToLogin`. In general this one is triggered when the cookie expired.

> 

```
 options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                
                OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                    {
                        //Do Your Things
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
            };
```